# inspect script in chrome debug without losing ability to scroll webpage

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

When I have some breakpoints set up in a script google chrome removes the ability to scroll the webpage, saying at the top of the screen `Paused in debugger`. Is there a way to disable this so that I can look at elements in various parts of the page, while also looking at the script in the debugger?

Answer (score 5):

Taken from [here](http://www.lukerodgers.ca/2012/10/scrolling-while-paused-in-chrome-debugger/).

An easy workaround for the scrolling lock-up is to just jump to the console, and:

`window.scrollTo(0, 800)`. (Replace 800 as needed)

Comment: this seems to work a bit better as it not only adjusts to your screen size, but accounts for the developer tools overlaying part of the window size: `window.scrollTo(0, window.scrollY+999)`

Answer (score 4):

You can click on the Elements tab and then hover over the HTML to the element you are interested in and right click to "Scroll into view". Not the most natural and fast, but it works...

Comment: Sadly, this does not seem to work to see the whole element if the element is partially visible - for instance, if there is a table and the top of it is barely visible, "Scroll into view" does nothing, whereas it would be more helpful to scroll up to see as much of the table as possible.

Comment: Worse than that, if the element was originally in view and you resize the developer tools so they obscure it, it STILL isn't possible to see it, even if you step over additional code (which I would expect would update the visibility flag to make it realize it should let you scroll to it).